# Use macbook as noise-cancelling headphones

Tags: osx, macbook

I don't own noise-cancelling headphones, but I have normal headphones and a macbook.

Is there an app I can get that will play the noise-cancelling noises through my headphones by using my macbook's microphone?

Comment: It can't be done. A noise canceling headphone works by measuring the noise just outside each ear and creating the opposite signal. The computer's microphone isn't in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to make a noise-cancelling program over speakers because the computer has no way of knowing distance from your ears to the speakers.

Noise-cancelling headphones scan for incoming sound and produce the opposite (canceling) wave. "Noise-cancelling headphones" are a misnomer - they counter incoming sound instead of blocking it.

If the noise-cancelling came from speakers, the computer would need to know where your ears are in real-time and that's just infeasible.

Comment: I think you are getting "speakers" and microphone confused; there are many problems, but the one you're tried to identify is that the computer doesn't know where the speakers (headphones) are in relation to the microphone of the computer.

Comment: @theonlygusti any progress on it ?

Comment: @rainyday it's impossible with current tech